# applicationWillEnterForeground 1 second before window addSubview adds view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a passcode screen setup in applicationWillEnterForeground, so this is called when the app has been closed then re-opened.

However, for about a second my main screen on my navigation controller / tab controller are shown before my pass code screen is shown, which isn't ideal.

I'm adding a view like this

```
 [window addSubview:myview.view];
```

Can anyone suggest how I can work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS takes a snapshot of your app when it goes background, you have to modify the view hierarchy **before** the app goes to background.

The snapshot is used for the app switcher and is shown for a short period when your app is resumed.

Since iOS 7 there is also a method on `UIApplication` called `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch` which could be helpful here.

Comment: OK, I've just tried that in applicationWillResignActive and it has no effect in the iOS7 simulator. Although if I hide my tab controller, it does that after I see the tab controller for a second.

Comment: Doesn't work on the device for me either :( reading elsewhere it sounds like it should, not sure what's happening?

Comment: You should also try calling `[window layoutIfNeeded]` and `[CATransaction flush]` after adding your subview as it forces a UI update. --- If it still doesn't work then please share more code.

Answer (score 0):

A work around I can think of is to add your subview in applicationDidEnterBackground, however this way will let you see a passcode screen among a carousel of apps after you double click the home button,I don't know if this behaviour is desired or not.